# PySide2 удалить виджет

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

Как удалить виджет на PySide2?

На C++ это делается так (насколько я понял и туториалов) (например удаление кнопки):

```
delete button;
```

На Python похожая конструкция:

```
del self.next_btn;
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*******.py", line 94, in dell
    del self.next_btn;
AttributeError: next_btn
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у объекта, на который ссылается `self`, нет атрибута `next_btn`. Объясните подробнее, чего пытаетесь добиться. Желательно показать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Атрибут есть, ошибка была в другом, уже разобрался и ответил на свой вопрос. А вот непрвильная информация (судя по всему) по ошибку и вводила в ступор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через [deleteLater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater):

```
self.next_btn.hide()
self.next_btn.deleteLater()
```

Comment: Такой способ тоже работает, спасибо.

Comment: Однако, в QVBoxLayout вызывает какие-то артефакты, пустоты появляются непонятные, потому в этом случает не подходит.

Comment: @froxxendsg, добавьте перед этим hide

Comment: Всё, разобрался, возможно это мои косяки были.

Answer (score 0):

Перед удалением нужно скрыть виджет:

```
self.next_btn.hide();
del self.next_btn;
```

Comment: Использовать с осторожностью, не знаю как на C++, но на Python такой способ почему то не освобождает память, или я что-то не правильно делаю, хотелось бы знать точно что происходит, но увы, спросить не у кого.